# Controlling build location with xcodebuild command line tool

Tags: macos, command-line, xcode4, xcodebuild

How can a build script figure where xcodebuild places the resulting application when calling
xcodebuild -scheme MyScheme archive ?

I understand that you can control the location via Xcode preferences but I would actually like to be able to specify this in the command line for my build script while keeping the default build location during development.

Comment: You can control the root location of other xcodebuild build artifacts with the argument DSTROOT="preferred/result/directory", but that doesn't work with `xcodebuild archive`. I am trying to find out to control the same thing and am not having any luck. I have looked here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html ... but it hasn't helped, even though it seems like a good place for such info.

Answer (score 1):

I have had minor luck with the following approaches:

1. Fiddle with the environment variable `BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR`. I remember this was somewhat infuriating.
2. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6101836/996184).
3. I used the method outlined [here](http://pilky.me/view/25), and did not fall too deeply into madness.

Plenty of ways to skin a cat, but remember you always end up with stains in your carpet.